# Entity Framework - insert data with "equal" (but not ReferenceEqual) reference properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EFCore. I have a few objects (Person) that contain certain navigation properties (Skill).
The Person-objects I'm having were created in such a way that several may have skills that have the same keys, however they are different objects, i.e. have different references. Assume I have no influence over the way these are created.

When I try to insert these via EFCore, I'm facing an exception because EFCore can't track several Skill objects with the same keys:

```
class Skill : IEquatable<Skill>
{
  string Name {get;set;}

  bool Equals(Skill other) { ... }
  override bool Equals(obj other) { ... }
  override int GetHashCode() { ... }
}

class Person
{
  string Name {get;set;}
  Skill Skill {get;set;}
}

var skill1 = new Skill { Name = "test skill" };
var person1 = new Person { Name = "Person2", Skill = skill1 };

var skill2 = new Skill { Name = "test skill" };
var person2 = new Person { Name = "Person2", Skill = skill2 };

var people = new [] { person1, person2 };

// skill1.Equals(skill2), but this will still throw an exception because EF can't track two skill objects with the same key
Context.People.AddRange(people);
```

In "principle", there should be no issue inserting this into the DB - the Skill objects have the same key, but are also equal, so there'd just need to be 1 INSERT into the database. Of course, this doesn't go well with how EF handles things, and how change tracking is handled.

The only way I can think of is, after the Person-objects are created (keep in mind, assumption is I cannot control this),
to manually loop through all Person objects I want to insert, and "unify" all navigation properties.
Or in other words, replace all Skill objects that are equal (Skill.Equals) with one and the same reference - either any taken from the objects to be added, or one retrieved from the database, in case it already contains a record with the needed key.y

While that would work in such a simple case, this gets very complicated in my real use case, which has a lot more reference properties, which have their own refereence properties and so on.

Is there any more standard / more efficient way of handling this issue?

Thanks

Comment: And can you at least modify classes (such as Skill)?

Comment: @Evk Yes, that I can. I have full control over the design of those objects. I just don't want to tangle up the part of the codebase where these are generated with any very EF or even repository specific code (e.g. query what objects already exist in the repository before the Person objects are created; the part where that happens doesn't even know there are repositories)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at least not easily.

Comment: Hmm, bummer. I will probably go down that -slightly cumbersome route of replacing dependencies .. thanks for your input!

Comment: And what will you do if key properties are the same but non-key properties are not? Or there are no non-key properties on those "skills"?

Comment: There are indeed; it would be very unlikely to run into that case in practice, the data should be fairly static, but in either case - if it happens, I'd update the existing record(s) in the DB.

Comment: I mean if I have one skill with id 1 and name "A" and another with id 1 and name "B", as navigation properties - you cannot decide which one is correct: they have the same key properties, but different non-key. So you don't know which to save\update in database.

Comment: Within the objects to be inserted that is? That case "should" be impossible to occur in my actual use case, but I'd likely at least check for that case and throw an exception if it happens